# Why create Mat object inside Thread get error 139?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, openmp

i have for in which i instantiate **Opencv Mat** object. then i'd like to parallelize that for loop using **omp**  procedure like in this example:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{

   Mat op_result = Mat(image.rows,image.cols,CV_8UC1, Scalar(0));

}
```

but my function exit with **error 139**. I've found that [post](http://answers.opencv.org/question/62557/parralel-creation-of-cvmat-crashes-bug/) which suggest to use that function:

```
//post suggestion
cv::MatAllocator *a0 = cv::Mat::getStdAllocator();

#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{

   Mat op_result = Mat(image.rows,image.cols,CV_8UC1, Scalar(0));

}
```

but i get this compiler error: **error: ‘getStdAllocator’ is not a member of ‘cv::Mat’**. how solve it ? why error 139 ?

Comment: which version of OpenCV are you using?

Comment: It is not a member of Mat. It is supposed to be a member of cv, on the post you linked...

Comment: @Omar my version is ** 2.4.13 **.
@LeonardoAlvesMachado i have also try with  `cv::MatAllocator *a0 = cv::getStdAllocator();` as you say but not work.

Comment: I guess was in version 3 when they added **getStdAllocator**

Comment: @Omar yes you're right but the 139 error not solved :_(

Comment: do you have more code in the parallel for? maybe the SIGSEGV (139) is thrown in a different line other than the Mat creation